# How to make the top left image link work for users with limited access?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I'm working on a Sharepoint site in the classic style where most users do not have permissions to access the site itself but only to read/edit a few lists and list items.
Those users do, however, have access to a Home.aspx site, which is the home page for the Sharepoint site.

Users with access to the site itself, are immediately redirected to
https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/YYYY/SitePages/Home.aspx
when entering/clicking on
https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/YYYY

For users with limited access only, this does not work, and they get the Access Denied page instead.

Is there a way to make the image in the top left corner link to
https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/YYYY/SitePages/Home.aspx instead of
https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/YYYY ?

Answer (score 0):

[Permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252funderstanding-permission-levels-in-sharepoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848)

[image]

As the article describes, **Limited Access permission** doesn't actually give the user the ability to see those items but is instead used under the covers to make things work (rendering the user experience, etc.)

For example, user won't be able to access item or library (for which user is granted access) using the site home page or regular site navigation.

So, when limited access users sign in site, page displays **Access Denied** message.

[image]

As long as you grant **Read permission** to these users at the **site level**, you can achieve your needs.

[image]

======================= **Updated Answer** =========================

By design, it is impossible to achieve your needs.

These two urls are different

- "**[https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test**"](https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test**%22) represents the entire site
  collection
- "**[https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/SitePages/Home.aspx**"](https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/SitePages/Home.aspx**%22) only
  represents the url of the homepage of the site collection

Therefore, users have access to the homepage does not mean that they can access the entire site collection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. 
Unfortunately, I am not allowed to grant those users Read permissions to the site itself becuase they must never see anything but the few lists and items which they are explicitely allowed to see.

Comment: Hi, Reggina. Thanks for you reply. If you only want those users to have Limited access permission, then they won’t have access to the home page

Comment: They do have access to the home page, because it does not inherit permissions. The issue is, that the link behind the image, does not lead to the Home.aspx with the unique permissions. I need to change that.

Comment: Hi, Reggina. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! I guess it's gonna be a jquery hack then.

Comment: Hi, Reggina. Thanks for your reply. If there are other solutions in the future, I will share with you as soon as possible.